# How to differentiate a time domain signal in the complex transfer function?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, transfer-function, integration

I have an input-output data set where the input is current and the output velocity. I am interested in the transfer function from current to acceleration though. So suppose:
$H(s) = \frac{I(s)}{V(s)}$
where $V$ is velocity and $I$ is current.
I thought that the solution would be to
$H'(S) = \frac{I(s)}{sV(s)} = \frac{I(s)}{A(s)}$ where A is the laplace transform of acceleration resulting in the transfer function I'm after. Now to MATLAB: I use 'tfestimate' to obtain the first transfer function $Txy$. Now I would suppose that substituting $s$ by $j \omega$ and implementing that to obtain the magnitude as $|\frac{Txy}{j\omega}|$ would yield the correct results. But I only get the correct results by using $|Txy \cdot j\omega|$ and comparing this to the differentiated signal of $v$. What error am I making? Is it actually the complete transfer function I want to multiply with $j\omega$ to achieve the differentiation instead of the denominator? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer function is commonly defined as output divided by input, and not so often the other way around (as you did in your question). [Also Matlab uses that more common definition](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html#bufqg3p). So the transfer function $H(s)$ between current $I(s)$ (input) and velocity $V(s)$ (output) would be defined by

$$H(s)=\frac{V(s)}{I(s)}\tag{1}$$

Since acceleration $A(s)$ is the derivative of velocity, we have

$$A(s)=sV(s)\tag{2}$$

Consequently, the transfer function between current and acceleration is

$$G(s)=\frac{A(s)}{I(s)}=\frac{sV(s)}{I(s)}=sH(s)\tag{3}$$